# unzip all .zip and .gz files from the subfolders of a particular folder using python

Tags: python, zip, gzip, os.walk

I was trying to unzip all .zip and .gz files from the subfolders of a particular folder. I want to extract all files in the same subfolder itself. I tried the code below. But I kept getting a file not found error.

```
import zipfile,fnmatch,os

rootPath = r"C:\boxes\am-2021\am-20216"
pattern = '*.zip' 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, pattern):
        #print(os.path.join(root, filename))
        zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root, filename)).extractall(os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(filename)[0]))
```

I got error like:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: "C:\\boxes\\am-2021\\am-20216\\fm\\mm"
```

Comment: Your code worked on my machine. So I would check if user running this code has write access to the folder where files should be extracted to and also can create new folders in there.

Answer (score 0):

This means you do not have the path present,
Now if the path is present, then try checking another path like if you are getting error in c://Docs then try c://downloads, if the problem persists then you might want to edit your system environment variables